# Finding minimum positive value and its position in each column of a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab

I need to find the minimum positive values in each column and its position inside the column of a certain matrix. So if I have:

```
A = [1 4
     2 3
     3 6]
```

I need to obtain the values 1 and 3, and the positions 1 and 2. Doing this inside a for loop I obtain correctly the minimum values and its position, but it also catches the negative values:

```
for bit = 1:2
    [y(bit),x(bit)] = min(A(:,bit));
end
```

And if I use:

```
[y(bit),x(bit)] = min(A(A(:,bit)>0));
```

I don't receive the expected result. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be easily achieved using `inf` and `min`...

---

#### New method using `inf` and no looping

Take some random example:

```
% Generated using A = randi([-100, 100], 10, 3)
A = [ 31    41   -12
     -93   -94   -24
      70   -45    53
      87   -91    59
      36   -81   -63
      52    65    -2
      49    39   -11
     -22   -37    29
      31    90    42
     -66   -94    51];
```

Set all negative values to *positive* infinity, which will ensure they are never the minimum value in the column.

```
A(A<=0) = inf; 
% if you want to preserve A, use A2=A; A2(A<=0)=inf;
```

Now you can just use the `min` function as expected.

```
[mins, idx] = min(A);
% mins = 31, 39, 29: as expected
% idx  = 1, 7, 8: the indices of the above values in each column as expected.
```

By default, `min` will get the column-wise minimum as you want.
To specify this explicitly, use `min(A,[],1)`, see [the documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) for more details.

**Note** that you could achieve the same result by using `NaN` instead of `inf`.

---

#### Your method

In response to why you were getting an unexpected result, it's because you weren't selecting the column of `A` in your loop, the second attempt should be corrected to

```
[y(bit),x(bit)] = min(A(A(:,bit)>0, bit));
```

**However**, this will still give an unexpected result! The minimums will be correct, but their indices will be lower than expected. This is because the indices will only count the positive values in each column, so you will get the nth *positive* number rather than the nth number. The easiest "workaround" is to abandon this method and use the quicker one above which doesn't require looping.

Comment: Good answer! I'd also add the dimension-along-which input to `min` to avoid possible confusion and because "_explicit is better than implicit_".

Comment: Thanks @Dev-iL, I've included a note about using `min` now.

Comment: The is a perfect answer. Thanks a lot Wolfie. It works great now!

Comment: No worries Pep, glad I could help!